# JAX-RS Jersey Client on Websphere 8.5

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, websphere-8

I'm trying to deploy jax-rs client application that use jersey on was 8.5.
I was hoping I won't need to pack jersey jars inside my war, because was will provide them.
But I'm getting this error when trying to invoke my servlet:

> Error 404: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: SRVE0203E: Servlet [HelloJAXRSClient]: example.HelloJAXRSClient was found, but is missing another required class. SRVE0206E: This error typically implies that the servlet was originally compiled with classes which cannot be located by the server. SRVE0187E: Check your class path to ensure that all classes required by the servlet are present.SRVE0210I: This problem can be debugged by recompiling the servlet using only the classes in the application's runtime

Is there something I can do to use was libraries so I won't need to pack them inside my applicaiton?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WebSphere 8.5 includes a JAX-RS implementation, but it's based on Apache Wink, not Jersey. So if you want to use what is already provided, I think you'll need to [create a Wink client](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twbs_jaxrs_impl_client_winkrestclient.html) instead of a Jersey one.

Or, you can [disable the WAS JAX-RS implementation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twbs_jaxrs_disable_runtime.html) which I'd guess will allow you to use Jersey instead, either deployed in your application or as a shared library as zargarf suggests.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shared library in the was admin console which point to a directory on the server. Then put your jar files in that directory. Associate the deployed application with the shared library. See: [http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.base.doc%2Finfo%2Faes%2Fae%2Ftcws_sharedlib.html](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/tcws_sharedlib.html)